# Error after importing Photon Pun 2 in Unity (Failed to find entry-points)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, photon-pun

I just imported pun 2 in Unity. Set up the app ID.
But whenever i make any changes in any of the script, it gives me this error:

```
"Failed to find entry-points"
```

Here is the full error:

```
Failed to find entry-points:
System.Exception: Unexpected exception while collecting types in assembly `PhotonUnityNetworking, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Photon3Unity3D, Version=4.1.6.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
  at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00105] in <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0 
  at zzzUnity.Burst.CodeGen.AssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) [0x00039] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) [0x00079] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00038] in <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00006] in <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0 
  at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve () [0x00006] in <ebb9e4250ed24cbfa42055e3532ef311>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.CollectGenericTypeInstances (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] types, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] visited) [0x0002f] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.CollectGenericTypeInstances (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] types, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] visited) [0x00057] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.FindEntryPoints (System.String[] rootAssemblyNames, Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompilerOptions options, Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.ProfileDelegate profileCallback, System.Boolean includeRootAssemblyReferences, System.Boolean splitTargets, Burst.Compiler.IL.Helpers.DebugLogWriter debugWriter) [0x0019d] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.FindEntryPoints (System.String[] rootAssemblyNames, Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, Burst.Compiler.IL.AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, Burst.Compiler.IL.NativeCompilerOptions options, Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.ProfileDelegate profileCallback, System.Boolean includeRootAssemblyReferences, System.Boolean splitTargets, Burst.Compiler.IL.Helpers.DebugLogWriter debugWriter) [0x001d9] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 
  at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.FindMethodsJob.Execute (Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.CompilerServerJobExecutionContext context) [0x00133] in <a2dd15248a25411e914af2a2c82fb63f>:0 

While compiling job:
```

I've worked with pun 2 previously but never encountered this error.

Comment: Which Unity version is this? Did you try to update that or use a slightly older one?
It looks like a Unity issue, really. Nothing in PUN uses Cecil

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the reply. I updated unity to latest version 2021.3.21f1. The error is still there. Also, earlier I was able to make a game using pun 2 in older 2021.3.15f1 and it worked just fine. But now suddenly there's an error.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a bug in 2021.3.21f1. Report it as bug / regression compared to 2021.3.15f1.